# How do you add more than one condition to a loop in MIPS assembly language?

Tags: loops, if-statement, assembly, conditional-statements

I am currently working on a homework problem for asssembly code that requires us to check whether a number is even or odd.  I am thinking of making an if/else loop that subtracts the given number by two until the number equals either 1 or 0, then checking which one it is so it can tell you that the number is odd or even (even if 0, odd if 1).  One problem I am having, however, is that I do not know how to add a condition that checks if the number is either 1 or 0.  Also, I'm not sure if I'm jumping to each loop correctly, as well as write up code that will tell the user in text that the number is even or odd.  Here is the code I am thinking up currently:

```
    addi s0,0,x                  #x is substituted with whatever number the user wants to check
    addi s1,0,2
    addi s2,0,0 
    addi s3,0,0

    bne s0, s2,else OR s0, s3,else       #Here, I want the code to check if s0 equals s2 or s3.  If so,
                                         #I want itt to jump to a second if statement that will tell you 
                                         #if the number is even or odd.  If it is not, I want it to jump 
                                         #a loop that subtracts by 2 again.
   else:                                  
       sub s0, s0, s1                      # Here I'm pretty sure I have my subtraction right, but how do 
                                           # I jump back to the for loop to check if it is 1 or 0 again?
```

Comment: Draw a flowchart if you are confused. That would be one way. Another would be to turn the 0 or 1 check into simply less than or equal to 1. PS: it is totally unnecessary to use a loop for even/odd checking. Just isolate the least significant bit with a single `andi $s0, $s0, 1`

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm pretty new to this language.  Would that single line of code really work?  Can you explain what exactly it does?

Comment: Do you know binary? The least significant bit is 0 or 1 for even or odd respectively. You can isolate that with a [bitwise and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bitwise_operation#AND). It's like in decimal if you want the remainder after division by 10 you just need to look at  the last digit. Has very little to do with the language.

Comment: I understand binary, but I just want to make sure that I would be putting the amount of appropriate information for the homework problem.  If I were to claim s0 was whatever number you were checking, say 54, and just write andi s0, s0, 1, would this be appropriate?

Comment: Yes that will isolate the lowest bit giving 0 for even, 1 for odd.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep the same logic to check whether the number is even or odd, you can use the following code where two beq statements are used (two conditions are checked). Basically, the program will take input a number from the user. It will keep subtracting 2 from the number until either 1 or 0 is reached. If 1 is reached, the number is odd. If 0 is reached, the number is even.

```
   .data
prompt: .asciiz "Enter the number : "

even: .asciiz "The given number is even "
odd: .asciiz "The given number is odd "


.text
.globl main

main:
li $s1, 1
li $s2, 0
li $s3, 2

li $v0, 4
la $a0, prompt  #prompt for the number
syscall

li $v0, 5
syscall
move $t1, $v0    #read number from console and store in $t1

check:
   beq $t1, $s1, odd1  #if the number is 1, go to odd
   beq $t1, $s3, even1 #if the number is 0, go to even
   sub $t1, $t1, $s3   # else subtract 2 from the number
   j check             #loop
odd1:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0, odd #print newline string # printing the number is odd
   syscall
   j exit
even1:
   li $v0, 4
   la $a0,even #print newline string # printing the number is even
   syscall


exit:
li $v0, 10
syscall
```

Comment: To subtract 2, just use `addiu $t1, $t1, -2`.  You don't need `2` in a different register.  Also, `$zero` is hard-wired to 0, you don't need `$s2` for that.

Comment: Of course for this particular problem, `andi $t1, $v0, 1` isolates the low bit in one instruction, no loop needed, but if you are going to loop, you can put one of the conditions at the bottom of the loop, like `bne $t1, $zero, check`, so you don't need a `j` instruction at all.